# Sequelize transaction always returning null

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm writing the backend for creating audit protocols. The user should be able to create criterias for the audit protocol. For this, i have the following backend-method to make sure, the protocol gets only created completely or the process of creating is canceled. It is possible to set several kinds of forms / criterias. But it could be, that only one kind of form is required. I do check that with the if-statement.

The creating works as expected. But the REST API always returns null to the clients. So i can't do further processing on the frontend regarding to the result of the creation process.

Technologies: Node.js and Sequelize. Frontend in angular / ionic. Database in mySQL.

I tried around with some transaction passing and return statements. I tried to compare it to a similiar code snippet, which works as expected.

```
exports.setAudit = (req, res, next) => {
  trueFalseCriteria = req.body.trueFalseForms;
  isShouldCriteria = req.body.isShouldForms;
  generalCriteria = req.body.generalForms;
  measurementCriteria = req.body.measurementForms;
  toolId = req.body.toolId;

  // Transaction is used to roll the whole transaction back if something wents wrong
  return sequelize
    .transaction(t => {
      return audit
        .create(
          {
            // Creating an audit referencing the tool
            toolId: toolId
          },
          { transaction: t }
        )
        .then(
          // Getting the id of the audit that we just created
          audit => {
            return audit.id;
          },
          { transaction: t }
        )
        .then(auditId => {
          // Check wether the kind of form is used or not. If so, sequelize tries to do a bulk insert into the databases.
          // Each bulk insert throws an error if it fails to cancel the whole transaction
          if (trueFalseCriteria) {
            console.log(1);
            trueFalseCriteria.forEach(dataEl => {
              dataEl.auditId = auditId;
            });
            trueFalseCriterion.bulkCreate(trueFalseCriteria).catch(err => {
              // Throw error to cancel transaction
              throw new Error(err);
            });
          }
          if (isShouldCriteria) {
            console.log(2);
            isShouldCriteria.forEach(dataEl => {
              dataEl.auditId = auditId;
            });
            isShouldCriterion.bulkCreate(isShouldCriteria).catch(err => {
              // Throw error to cancel transaction
              throw new Error(err);
            });
          }
          if (generalCriteria) {
            console.log(3);
            generalCriteria.forEach(dataEl => {
              dataEl.auditId = auditId;
            });
            generalCriterion.bulkCreate(generalCriteria).catch(err => {
              // Throw error to cancel transaction
              throw new Error(err);
            });
          }
          if (measurementCriteria) {
            console.log(4);
            measurementCriteria.forEach(dataEl => {
              dataEl.auditId = auditId;
            });
            measurementCriterion.bulkCreate(measurementCriteria).catch(err => {
              // Throw error to cancel transaction
              throw new Error(err);
            });
          }
        }, { transaction: t });
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(5);
      res.status(200).json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {

      console.log(6);
      if (!err.statusCode) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
      }
      next(err);
    });
};
```

Expected result: Http response with status code 200 on success
Actual result: null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a `return` for the last `.then()`:

```
.then(auditId => {
   // Check wether the kind of form is used or not. If so, sequelize tries to do a bulk insert into the databases.
   .....
   if (measurementCriteria) {
       ....
   }
// RETURN SOMETHING HERE 
}, { transaction: t });
```

Comment: Thanks, @KenOn10. Don't know how i overlooked it for so long. In addition, i had to set returning: true to bulkCreate.